# bash script, with multiple scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created 2 bash scripts. If I run:

```
./script2 $1 $2 $3
```

the script works as intended; however if I run call script 2 using script 1 it seems to fail.

### script1

```
while read line; do
    echo $line > values
    name1=$(cat values | tr ';' '\n' | grep -v tftp)
    name2=$(cat values | tr ';' '\n' | grep tftp)
    echo $name1
    echo $name2
    ./script2 $name1 $name2 $3
done < /home/list
```

As far as I can tell my expect commands seem in script2 seem to be failing when initialized by script1. I get the following output, but it doesn't show my files transfer, whereas if I were to initialize script2 manually I would see file transfers taking place.

```
blucero@tftp password: spawn scp -r file1 tftp1:.
blucero@tftp password: spawn scp -r file2 tftp1:.
```

### Script2 is just a series of file transfers to various tftp boxs

```
expect -c "spawn scp -r /home/file1 tftp1.$1:. ; expect password: ; send $3\r ; interact ;"
expect -c "spawn scp -r /home/file2 tftp1.$1:. ; expect password: ; send $3\r ; interact ;"
expect -c "spawn scp -r /home/file3 tftp1.$1:. ; expect password: ; send $3\r ; interact ;"
expect -c "spawn scp -r /home/file3 tftp1.$1:. ; expect password: ; send $3\r ; interact ;"
```

Comment: I do not see script1 in your code. How are you running it?

Comment: script1 is the script that I am initailizing from the bash prompt. I run it just by typing ./script1

Comment: Please add what script2 is doing, preferably the contents for script2, and what exactly you expect would/should happen when everything works as expected.

Comment: Your `script1` has a `$3`, but no `$1` or `$2`. That's almost certainly a mistake. (From your comment, it seems that it shouldn't have any parameters at all?)

Comment: script2 has now been added to original post

Comment: It really isn't clear what's going on that you don't expect, but there's a moderate chance that the fact that the standard input of `script2` is a file, not your terminal, when it is run by `script1` means that you are getting different behaviour out of the programs run by `script2`.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of `script1` so you can see all the commands as it's executing them, with the variables filled in. This should help you debug it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that seems to be my thoughts as well though I am not sure why. If I run independently and input the variables the file transfers take place, If script one calls script2 and enters the variables on my automatically the file transfers don't take place. (Sorry if I wasn't clear on that earlier)

Comment: using set -x I can see all 3 varliables successfully pass to script2. I have replaced them with generic statments as to not post internal information in a public forum:  ++ ./script2 (LOC) (server) (password)

Comment: One curiosity: your `script2` does not seem to use `$2` at all.

Comment: $2 is a variable I am not yet using, it's still a work in progress and I have not yet gotten far enough to require $2

Comment: And if you change `send $3` to `send $2` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your arguments to script2 in quotes (in the script1 shell script):

```
./script2 "$name1" "$name2" "$3"
```

It looks like you have special shell characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: I think you'd need six double quotes, not just two; the script appears to take three separate arguments.

Comment: Yes, correct this would treat them as a single argument.  Updated answer.  Thanks much.

Comment: I actually found this solution on this site earlier when I was taking a look around, It actually had no affect.